# Color with different color in list view

Tags: android, listview, android-custom-view

I have a simple list view and i have to color every alternative row with different color.

Is it possible to color listView with different color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Assuming ArrayAdapter, you will have to do something like this:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

   ...

   if (position % 2 == 0) { // Even numbered row
      // set a color as background for view
   } else { // Odd numbered row
      // set another color as background for view
   }

   ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to color listView with different color.?

Yes, its possible. You can use a listview with custom adapter.

Follow this [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html) ..

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, its possible** , for this use `getView()`

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

   ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    if (position == 0){
    holder.layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
   }
    if (position == 1){
    holder.layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
   }
}
```

So On.....

Comment: can you explain about holder .what is this